# Can gcloud builds submit run in background?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm trying to automate my builds using Google Cloud Build. For various reasons the primary use flow will be to manually kick off builds rather than using a Github trigger.

Right now it looks like when you run

```
gcloud builds submit .
```

it kicks off the build process but *the gcloud command must stay running for the build to continue*. If I Ctrl-C it then it stops the entire build process.

I could run it in the background but presumably if I get disconnected from the network or my laptop goes to sleep that will also interrupt the build process(?)

Clearly the build can run in the background since that's what a Github trigger does; is there any way I can do the same thing from the command line?

Comment: What's your platform ? Linux ? Windows ?

Answer (score 3):

If you add `--async` to your `gcloud builds ...` command, the job will be run asynchronously, as a long-running operation.

You may query the state of this operation in order to determine the state of the build.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit

Alternatively, you may use something like Linux `screen` to keep any job running after you detach.